# Interpretation of $\mathbb R^d \times \{1,2\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, elementary-set-theory, notation

I need help with this notation from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm#Statistical_setting):

> Suppose we have pairs $(X_1,Y_1), (X_2,Y_2), \dots, (X_n,Y_n)$ taking values in $\mathbb R^d \times \{1,2\}$.

Does it mean the following:

$X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ are the first elements in the pairs so they take values in the set $\mathbb R^d$.
\begin{align}
X_1 &\in \mathbb R^d, 
\quad \text{i.e.} \quad 
X_1=(X_{11}, X_{12}, \dots, X_{1d} )
\tag 1
\\
X_2 &\in \mathbb R^d,
\quad \text{i.e.} \quad 
X_2=(X_{21}, X_{22}, \dots, X_{2d} )
\tag 2
\\
&\vdots \\
X_n &\in \mathbb R^d,
\quad \text{i.e.} \quad 
X_n=(X_{n1}, X_{n2}, \dots, X_{nd} )
\tag 3
\\
\end{align}
$Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_n$ are the second elements in the pairs so they take *one value* in the set $\{1,2\}$, i.e. $1$ *or* $2$.
\begin{align}
Y_1 &\in \{1,2\},
\quad 
\text{i.e.}
\quad
Y_1=1 \quad \text{or} \quad Y_1=2
\tag 4
\\
Y_2 &\in \{1,2\},
\quad 
\text{i.e.}
\quad
Y_2=1 \quad \text{or} \quad Y_2=2
\tag 5
\\
&\vdots 
\\
Y_n &\in \{1,2\},
\quad 
\text{i.e.}
\quad
Y_n=1 \quad \text{or} \quad Y_n=2
\tag 6
\end{align}

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct.